# Detect Unicode Character in string

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have string input. I want to check all the characters and prompt the user if there is any Unicode character in input string.

How can I do this validation in C++.

eg. In Notepad if you enter any Unicode character and try to save it with ANSI Encoding, it will prompt about Unicode character. I want to do similar validation.

Comment: You need to specify how you are storing the data in the string - is it a std::string with UTF-8 or a std::wstring with UTF-16? You also are probably asking whether the character cannot be represented in 7-bit ASCII ( or possibly 8-bit ASCII plus a code page ), as all ASCII characters also have Unicode codepoints.

Comment: If you think it's possible you could have a string that **doesn't** have Unicode characters in it, you almost certainly need to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I am using LPTSTR in VC++.And you got my point correctly. I am want to detect the character which can't be represented by 8 Bit ASCII or extended ASCII.

Comment: There's no such thing as 8 bits ASCII, and there are hundreds of extensions to ASCII. One such extension is UTF-8, and it supports all Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Notepad warns you about is slightly different: It warns you about Unicode characters that cannot be converted to the desired code page. IOW, `WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,  ..., &lpUsedDefaultChar)` causes `lpUsedDefaultChar` to be set to TRUE.

Substitute `CP_ACP` for the encoding you want, except `CP_UTF8` which makes no sense. UTF8 supports all Unicode characters.

Comment: Thanks this solution has solved the exact requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can use IsTextUnicode function. That's the function notepad uses as far as I know.

MSDN-Link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318672%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Just insert NULL as the last parameter.

```
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "Hallo!";
  std::wstring ws = L"Hello!";

  if (::IsTextUnicode(ws.c_str(), ws.length(), NULL) == 1)
  {
    // is unicode
    int i = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    // no unicode
    int i = 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the link or any sample as I am confused with last parameter.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial about writing a text editor. He'a also covers encoding and how to handle this. http://www.catch22.net/tuts/neatpad

Comment: Thanks for sample code!!WideCharToMultiByte() has solved the exact requirement.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to allow Unicode and store the text as UTF-8. As UTF-8 is a superset of ASCII it's very easy to find characters which are not ASCII (they have the high bit set).